# Installing pip librarry on remote server connected via ssh

Tags: ssh, pip, remote-server

I'm trying to install `unidecode` library on remote server device, which I have connected using `ssh`. But when I run `pip install unidecode`, I'm getting this output.

[image]

Comment: Try to run `pip install --upgrade pip` before

Comment: Getting same output on doing this